# How to Outer Join a Table onto a Subset of a Query

Tags: sql

Suppose you have a query that returns a record set like the following:

```
Date      |   Code  | Val 1  | Val 2
1/1/2016       A       1        2
1/1/2016       B       3        4
1/2/2016       A       5        6
1/2/2016       B       7        8
1/2/2016       C       9        10
```

And a second table that contains all possible values for "Code" from the subquery:

```
Code
A
B
C
D
```

How can the two sets be joined such that a record is added to the resultant query for each missing Code from the second table for *each date* in the first.  In the example above the resultant query should be:

```
Date      |   Code  | Val 1  | Val 2
1/1/2016       A       1        2
1/1/2016       B       3        4
1/1/2016       C       NULL    NULL
1/1/2016       D       NULL    NULL
1/2/2016       A       5        6
1/2/2016       B       7        8
1/2/2016       C       9        10
1/2/2016       D       NULL     NULL
```

An outer join on the Code column works for a single day, but because the date is not included in the second set (or the join), it does not work when applied to a set that spans multiple dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (DateField DATE      ,   Code CHAR  , Val1  INT, Val2 INT)
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
('1/1/2016','A','1','2'),
('1/1/2016','B','3','4'),
('1/2/2016','A','5','6'),
('1/2/2016','B','7','8'),
('1/2/2016','C','9','10')

CREATE TABLE #Code (Code CHAR )
INSERT INTO #Code
VALUES('A'),
('B'),
('C'),
('D')
```

Query:

1. get the cartesian product of all distinct dates within #temp and all codes within #Code and place in the Common Table Expression CTE
2. LEFT OUTER JOIN #temp with the Common Table Expression CTE on Code
   and DateField

Query:

```
WITH CTE AS ( SELECT * 
              FROM (SELECT DISTINCT DateField 
                    FROM #temp) AS A CROSS JOIN 
                    #Code AS C
            )
SELECT C.*,t.Val1,t.Val2 
FROM CTE AS C LEFT OUTER JOIN  
     #temp AS t ON c.Code=t.Code AND c.DateField=t.DateField
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't say which database you are using; if you don't have CTE available you can also use a `Calendar` table.

*I've assumed your data is a table of `Orders`, just to give the table a name.*

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(order_date date
 ,code varchar(1)
 ,val_1 int
 ,val_2 int);

INSERT INTO Orders
    ([order_date], [code], [val_1], [val_2])
VALUES
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00', 'A', 1, 2),
    ('2016-01-01 00:00:00', 'B', 3, 4),
    ('2016-01-02 00:00:00', 'A', 5, 6),
    ('2016-01-02 00:00:00', 'B', 7, 8),
    ('2016-01-02 00:00:00', 'C', 9, 10);

CREATE TABLE Codes(code CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO Codes(code) VALUES 
('A'),
('B'),
('C'),
('D');

CREATE TABLE Calendar(calendar_date DATE);
INSERT INTO Calendar(calendar_date) VALUES
('1/1/2016'),
('1/2/2016')
```

You can then join these to get all `codes` for each day

```
SELECT calendar_date, T.code, val_1, val_2
FROM 
    (SELECT calendar_date, code FROM Codes CROSS JOIN Calendar) AS T
LEFT JOIN Orders ON T.calendar_date = Orders.order_date
AND T.code = Orders.code
ORDER BY calendar_date, T.code
```

Query result

```
calendar_date   code    val_1   val_2
-------------   ----    -----   -----
"2016-01-01"    "A"     "1"     "2"
"2016-01-01"    "B"     "3"     "4"
"2016-01-01"    "C"     "NULL"  "NULL"
"2016-01-01"    "D"     "NULL"  "NULL"
"2016-01-02"    "A"     "5"     "6"
"2016-01-02"    "B"     "7"     "8"
"2016-01-02"    "C"     "9"     "10"
"2016-01-02"    "D"     "NULL"  "NULL"
```

An advantage of the calendar table is when you want to populate your result with all days and codes, even if there is not a matching row in the main table. For example, adding another date produces the result

```
calendar_date   code    val_1   val_2
-------------   ----    -----   -----
"2016-01-01"    "A"     "1"     "2"
"2016-01-01"    "B"     "3"     "4"
"2016-01-01"    "C"     "NULL"  "NULL"
"2016-01-01"    "D"     "NULL"  "NULL"
"2016-01-02"    "A"     "5"     "6"
"2016-01-02"    "B"     "7"     "8"
"2016-01-02"    "C"     "9"     "10"
"2016-01-02"    "D"     "NULL"  "NULL"
"2016-01-03"    "A"     "NULL"  "NULL"
"2016-01-03"    "B"     "NULL"  "NULL"
"2016-01-03"    "C"     "NULL"  "NULL"
"2016-01-03"    "D"     "NULL"  "NULL"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `cross join` and  a `left join`:

```
select d.date, c.code, q.val1, q.val2
from (select distinct date from q) d cross join
     codes c left join
     q
     on d.date = q.date and c.code = q.code;
```

The `cross join` generates all the rows.  The `left join` brings in the values you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (SQL server)

```
DECLARE @dataTable TABLE (SampleDate DATE, Code CHAR(1), VALUE1 VARCHAR(10), VALUE2 VARCHAR(10));

INSERT INTO @dataTable (SampleDate, Code, VALUE1, VALUE2)
VALUES
('1/1/2016', 'C', 3, 2),
('1/1/2016', 'A', 3, 2),
('1/2/2016', 'A', 6, 4),
('1/5/2016', 'B', 9, 8);

DECLARE @Codes TABLE (Code CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO @Codes (Code)
VALUES
('A'),
('B'),
('C'),
('D');

 WITH DateList AS (
    SELECT CAST('2016-01-01' AS date) AS [DateKey]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY,1,[DateKey])
    FROM    DateList   
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY,1,[DateKey]) <= CAST('2016-12-31' AS date))

SELECT s.DateKey, s.Code, dat.VALUE1, dat.VALUE2

FROM @dataTable dat RIGHT JOIN (
                SELECT  d.DateKey, c.Code
                FROM    @Codes c, DateList d) s 
    ON dat.Code = s.Code AND dat.SampleDate = s.DateKey

ORDER BY s.DateKey, s.Code
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[image]